# Access double nested object and return key value pairs

Tags: javascript, object, nested, extract

I have an object with the following structure: (look at the arrays called `dataValues`).

```
{
pager: {
    page: 1,
    pageCount: 1,
    total: 0,
    pageSize: 50
},
events: [{
        storedBy: "admin",
        dueDate: "2017-07-12T19:11:19.801",
        dataValues: [{
                dataElement: "F3ogKBuviRA",
                value: "[-10.33505,8.46094]",
            },
            {
                dataElement: "oZg33kd9taw",
                value: "Female",
            }
        ],
        notes: []
    },
    {
        storedBy: "admin",
        dueDate: "2017-07-12T19:11:11.449",
        dataValues: [{
                dataElement: "pzsJKs59JsY",
                value: "G-3707",
            },
            {
                dataElement: "AmO6YwrO46f",
                value: "Male",
            },
        ],
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to access every nested array `dataValues` and return an object of pairs of key:values where the key is the value of *dataElement* and the value is the value of *value*:

`dataElement: value => oZg33kd9taw: "Female"`. In the end, I want to construct a GeoJSON like so:

```
{
type: "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        type: "Point",
        "coordinates": [-10.33505, 8.46094]
    },
    "properties": {
        //inject extracted values here!!
        oZg33kd9taw: "Female",
        pzsJKs59JsY: "G-3707"
    }
}]
}
```

I've attempted to implement a recursive function that goes deep into the object until it can no longer find nested objects, and then return the values:

```
function eachRecursive(obj){
  for (var k in obj){
  if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null)
    eachRecursive(obj[k]);
    if (obj.dataValues != undefined) {
        obj.dataValues.forEach(d => {console.log(d)})
      console.log(obj.dataValues);
    }
  }
}
```

This is not working as intended, as it returns the values n times (with n being the number of existing dataValues arrays inside the object). Any suggestions or solutions using vanilla JS or lodash, ramda or similar libraries is greatly appreciated. If I could extract the value pairs into an array of arrays or a separate object that would be already a lot of help. Thanks!

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zrLnva0u/6/

Comment: Why do you use recursion? There's no arbitrary nesting in your data, it's only two levels. So use two nested loops, one for the `events` and one for the `dataValues`.

Comment: What happened to `Male` in your GeoJSON? And why did `F3ogKBuviRA` became the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

What @Bergi said...

```
var pairs = {};

data.events.forEach(event => {
  event.dataValues.forEach(el => {
    pairs[el.dataElement] = el.value;
  });
});

console.log(pairs)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0gxrudy0/

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tom. THere's a slight problem though, since not all dataValues arrays have the same length (I realize I forgot to mention that), I probably need an array of arrays with objects inside. Check the variable demo on the fiddle for an example https://jsfiddle.net/0gxrudy0/2/

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of back and forth, this is the solution in case someone wonders:

```
    data.events.forEach((event) => {
        cases.push(event.dataValues);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
        var dataValues = cases[i];
        var object = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < dataValues.length; j++) {
            var d = dataValues[j];
            object[d.dataElement] = d.value;
        }
        test.push(object);
    }
```

This returns an array of arrays, where each array contains an object with the `dataElement: value` pairs.